# How to show that absolute convergence is equivalent to permutable convergence.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I'm having difficulty understanding what this proposition is stating. I'm to show in $\Bbb R^n$ that absolute convergence of the series is equivalent to permutable convergence.

I've searched my book, Undergraduate Topology by Robert Kasriel, but I cannot find any definitions for these terms. In class I was given the following definitions:

$\sum a_j$ = absolutely convergent if (U$_k$), U$_k$ = $\sum_{j=1}^k$ |a$_k$|

$\sum$ a$_n$ = permutably convergent if $\forall \sigma$: $\Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N$, (U$_\sigma,_k$), U$_\sigma,_k$ = $\sum_{j=1}^k$ = a$_\sigma,_j$

I'm at my desk saying "What does this mean? Whatdoesthismeanwhatdoesthismean!?"

I don't want anyone to write the proof for me, because I wouldn't even understand it. I am lost in the notation. I expect I'll end up using the Cauchy Criterion for convergence but I can't apply it if I don't even understand the definitions. Please send help!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing you know what an absolutely converging series is, if not, this is just a sequence of numbers (in $R$) lets say $\{a_n\}$ such that when we take the sum of the absolute value of each term as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get a finite answer.

What the second statement regarding 'permutably convergent' series says that if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely then the series obtained by by any rearrangement of the terms ($a_n$) also converges absolutely (in fact to the same limit).

If you want to attempt the proof, note that there exists a bijection $\sigma: Z^+ \rightarrow Z^+$ such that the series can be written $\sum V_{\sigma(n)}$. Also, given $\epsilon$ there exists an $N$ such that if $m,n>N$ then $|a_m|+\dots +|a_n|<\epsilon$. Moreover since $\sigma$ is injective we can choose $N_1>N$ to be so large that if $n>N_1$ then $\sigma(n)>N$, now what can you say about the partial sums of the series $\sum |V_{\sigma(n)}|$?

Comment: This seems to address a proof of how absolute convergence implies permutable convergence, but not the other direction. However it probably doesn't matter because OP specified that a proof probably wasn't necessary.

Comment: Indeed. Just wanted to give a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand the definitions now. To answer your question @dable, the partial sums of the series $\sum$ |$V_\sigma(n)$| would also converge to a finite sum?

Comment: You've got it (since the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence).

Comment: I greatly appreciate you, I believe I can attempt to prove this now.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to comment if you need anymore help.